# How to shrink the prompt of a long path using environment variables in OS X (extend '~')

Tags: macos, command-line, zsh, environment-variables

I've seen this working with the gemset environment, I would like to reproduce it now that I need to work on a very indented directory path.

Basically I had a `$GEM_HOME` environment variable pointing to `~/.rvm/somewhere`. Whenever I `cd ~/.rvm/somewhere/someSubdir` my prompt would be: `giulio@Giulios-MacBook-Pro:$GEM_HOME/someSubdir`.

It was very nice and compact and so now I would like to shrink my oh-my-zsh prompt as I'm working now on a Parallels windows box, and I have a very long path in my prompt,

I would like to:

`export WIN_HOME=/Users/giulio/Documents/Parallels/Windows\ 8.pvm/Windows\ Disks/C`

so that when I'm in `/Users/giulio/Documents/Parallels/Windows\ 8.pvm/Windows\ Disks/C/Users` the prompt would just show `WIN_HOME/USERS`.

Basically I would like to obtain the behavior of `~` that refers to `/Users/giulio` for my user with some additional directories.

How can I get that?

thanks,

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `hash -d` to set *Static Named Directories* (just like user homes):

```
hash -d WIN_HOME='/Users/giulio/Documents/Parallels/Windows 8.pvm/Windows Disks/C'
```

Instead of the whole path *zsh* will show `~WIN_HOME`. You can also go to this directory by `cd ~WIN_HOME`.

*Static Named Directories* are automatically created for user homes ( `~someuser` points to the home directory of "someuser"). Also for parameters that contain absolute paths (In your case `$GEM_HOME`) once they are accessed with `~` followed by the parameter name (`~GEM_HOME`) or if the option `AUTO_NAME_DIRS` is set.

`hash -d` has the advantage that you do not need to clutter your environment with parameters.

For the prompt *zsh* will always use the shortest representation of a path. So if you set `hash -d temporary_directory=/tmp/foo`, the prompt will show `/tmp/foo` and not `~temporary_directory`.

Answer (score 2):

I figured that ZSH has an option called `AUTO_NAME_DIRS`, which tells ZSH to expand the directories like I want.

I just had to `setopt autonamedirs` in the shell and set the env variable. and it worked :)